# Find or create kernel configuration of kernel binary

Tags: kernel, configuration

I've downloaded a kernel binary which I am using now. In order to use the watchdog on my system I must recompile the kernel with watchdog support. Is it possible to obtain the current kernel configuration of the binary?

The binary is obtained from [this](http://www.acmesystems.it/binary_repository) page. I've used version R5.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/51032/how-do-i-check-what-kernel-options-were-compiled-without-looking-at-boot-config

Comment: Just using the same config could be not enough if they've patched the kernel or there are proprietary drivers, you must look if they provide a way to re-build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the kernel config is not distributed in `/boot/config-*` or available at `/proc/config.gz`, it is nearly impossible to get it. As Alex wrote, they could also have patched the kernel and included proprietary drivers.

But because the kernel is under [GPLv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), the owner of the site where you download the binaries, have to give you the corresponding configuration including the source code they used to compile it. In the case you get problems, contact [gpl-violations.org](http://gpl-violations.org/).

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can first cd into your new kernel source code directory, there you just type this:

```
make oldconfig
```

Then it will ask you for all the options which didn't exist in the old kernel versions. the ones which exist in both, the currently running and the new version, are simply copied. Afterwards you type the following to do your customizations:

```
make menuconfig
```